# updating mysql table with facebook query result

Tags: php, mysql

I have table where i got facebook event id's.

```
id    event_id    attendings
 1    12345678
```

I will take event_id and put it into query:

```
$query = 'https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+attending_count+FROM+event+WHERE+eid='.$event_id.'&access_token='.$params1['access_token'];
$result = file_get_contents($query);
$obj = json_decode($result, true);
foreach ($obj['data'] as $item) { 
$attend = $item['attending_count'];
}
```

Now i will update table attendings where event_id = 12345678 with $attend

The question is: How can i do it with all the rows i got in my table

Thanks

Sorry for my spelling, english not my mother tonque.

Comment: Which content exactly do you want to store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch all of the desired `attending_count` values with a single FQL query, then update your existing table from within a loop over the results:

```
define('FB_FQL_API', 'https://graph.facebook.com/fql?');

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$qry = $dbh->query('
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(event_id)
  FROM   my_table
');

$upd = $dbh->prepare('
  UPDATE my_table
  SET    attendings = :attend
  WHERE  event_id   = :event
');

$fql = '
  SELECT eid, attending_count
  FROM   event
  WHERE  eid IN ('.$qry->fetchColumn().')
';

$url = FB_FQL_API . http_build_query([
  'q'            => trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $fql)),
  'access_token' => $params1['access_token']
]);

$res = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));

foreach ($res->data as $event) $upd->execute([
  ':attend' => $event->attending_count,
  ':event'  => $event->eid
]);
```

Comment: It seems that the script can't put more than 20 events in the $url, theres some kind of limitation, last event_id is cut. Any ideas?

Comment: @kristjanzzz: It could be due to [`group_concat_max_len`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len).

Comment: I can't use "SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len=var" without root access?

Comment: @kristjanzzz: So don't set it globally - just set it for your session.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you will need to do this all in a big loop since you must do the facebook API call for each event.

So first step would be to get all the result from teh table using whatever MySQL library you are choosing to use. The query would be:

```
SELECT id, event_id FROM table;
```

Let's say that as you looped through your result set you assigned the data to an array like this:

```
$array[$row['id']] = $row['event_id'];
```

Now, you would loop through that array like this:

```
foreach($array as $db_id => $event_id) {
    // your facebook code here

    // update the database with your library of choice using this query
    UPDATE table SET attendings = $attending WHERE id = $db_id
}
```